# I got the query to search a line for a pattern using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Search each line of a file for a pattern and if pattern exists in a file, search whether the very next line starts and ends with the same pattern. If yes, delete the line.

input is like:

```
abd dgf & dhdj
& hjsdhkl kjk &
dfjhfjkk
fjdfhjf & 
sdhjgfsdg
& dghdf &
hfjsdhj
```

the ouput will be like this:

```
abd dgf & dhdj

dfjhfjkk
fjdfhjf & 
sdhjgfsdg
& dghdf &
hfjsdhj
```

Here `'&'` is my pattern. I used several options with sed. But none of them gives me correct output.
i used var=`sed -n "/$1/{n;p}" $2 | grep "^$1" | grep "$1$"`
  sed -i "/^$var$/d" $2 .but it won't work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the several options you used, so that we don't suggest a solution that you've already tried.

Comment: var=`sed -n "/$1/{n;p}" $2 | grep "^$1" | grep "$1$"`
sed -i "/^$var$/d" $2       .But it wont work

Comment: @sans Please edit the question to add information like that, instead of just commenting.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to

> search whether the very next line starts and ends with the same pattern. If yes, delete the line.

Do you mean that in the same way that `uniq` does? If so, you're welcome. Though I don't see that as the implication in your example.

Do you *need* to use `sed`?
If not then what about:

```
$ perl -nE\
'if($follows_match && /^\&/ && /\&$/){print"\n"}else{print};$follows_match=/\&/;'\
each.txt file.txt input.txt as.txt arg.txt list.txt isProcessed.txt toSTDOUT.txt
```

Does what you ask in the in/out example.

The `sed` script that does the same is (in my opinion) even harder to read:

```
$ sed '
/\&/ {
N
s/\n\&.*\&$/\
/ 
}' input_file.txt
```

Now, to me, "delete the line" *does not mean* "replace the line with a blank line". Which if you take this meaning rather than what's shown in your input and output examples you get a slightly cleaner looking:

```
$ sed '
/\&/ {
N
s/\n\&.*\&$// 
}' input_file.txt
```

or in perl:

```
$ perl -nE 'print unless $m && /^\&/ && /\&$/; $m=/\&/;'\
input_file.txt
```

I hope this is **NOT** your homework regarding learning `sed` because you just didn't learn much.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.But i need to use sed for the solution.

Comment: search for '&' (pattern) on every line.If a match is found,check whether the very next line starts and ends with the same pattern.If yes delete that line.Otherwise leave the line unchanged

Comment: @sans kindy punctuate and format for increased attention on this site.